# How can I collect logs from Linux running in VirtualBox in an external file?

Tags: logging, virtualbox, rsyslog

I'm developing some software, and running it in VirtualBox to test it. However, it keeps hanging the whole VM - I can't use the console, SSH in, etc. This makes the failure rather hard to debug. The application is writing logs, but when the machine hangs, I have no idea if they are successfully written to disk or not.

Is there some way I can capture live logs in an external file, so that I can monitor it even when I can't access the VM?

Comment: I'm not sure this on on-topic for SO, and it seems [there is some uncertainty](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286079/questions-off-topic-about-virtualmachine-and-command-line/286081). I'm happy to move it if there's a better place for it.

Answer (score 1):

If your software logs using syslog, or can be connected to syslog via [logger](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html) or a [process supervisor](https://askubuntu.com/a/490900/250427), then you can export the logs over a virtual serial port, and capture the output of that into a file.

First of all, set up a serial port in VirtualBox:

1. Stop the VM
2. Go to Context Menu > Settings > Ports
3. Check 'Enable Serial Port'
4. Set 'Port Number' to 'COM1'
5. Set 'Port Mode' to 'Raw File'
6. Set 'Path/Address' to '/tmp/serial.log' or some other suitable path on the host
7. Start the VM

Then, inside the VM, configure syslog to log to that serial port. Assuming you have [rsyslog](http://www.rsyslog.com/), do:

```
# give the syslog user access to serial ports by adding it to the right group
# 'dialout' in the Debian family, 'uucp' in the Red Hat clan; check local listings
sudo usermod -a -G dialout syslog

cat <<EOF >/etc/rsyslog.d/99-serial.conf
daemon,mail.*;\
       news.=crit;news.=err;news.=notice;\
       *.=debug;*.=info;\
       *.=notice;*.=warn       /dev/ttyS0
EOF
service rsyslog restart
```

Note that COM1 should appear in Linux as /dev/ttyS0. If you use a different serial port, it may be a different device.